# How to check multiple contains operations faster?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a String list as below. I want to do some calculations based on if this list has multiple elements with same value.

I got nearly 120k elements and when I run this code it runs too slow. Is there any faster approach than contains method?

```
List<String> words= getWordsFromDB();  //words list has nearly 120k elements
List<String> tempWordsList = new LinkedList<String>();  //empty list

String[] keys = getKeysFromDB();
List<String> tempKeysList = new LinkedList<String>();

for (int x = 0; x < words.size(); x++) {

    if (!tempWordsList.contains(words.get(x))) {
      tempWordsList.add(words.get(x));

      String key= keys[x];
      tempKeysList.add(key);
    } else {
        int index = tempWordsList.indexOf(words.get(x));

        String m = tempKeysList.get(index);
        String n = keys[x];
        if (!m.contains(n)) {
            String newWord = m + ", " + n;
            tempKeysList.set(index, newWord);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** words list comes from database and problem is there is a service continuously updating and inserting data to this table. I don't have any access to this service and there are other applications who is using the same table.

**EDIT2:** I have updated for full code.

Comment: With this much data, have you thought about loading it into a database and setting up an index on that column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen looks like they're already in a DB, and he's not using its power wisely.

Comment: `!contains()` does a whole run through the list then `indexOf` runs through most of it again (on average): Just use `indexOf` and if it returns -1 then the word isn;t in the list.

Comment: Don't use a `LinkedList` as tempList, but something like a `HashSet`

Comment: You can use a HashMap that maps the word to an index.

Comment: fetch only the words from the database that have count(distinct) > 1

Comment: Can't you affect what `getWordsFromDB()` does? It's a waste of time (both processing and developer) to do this in Java code, if you can do it before you even fetch the results from the database.

Comment: and you are fetching the data through the service or direct from the db? If you cannot alter the SQL you could use a HashMap with the word as key and a counter as value.

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedList.get()` runs in O(N) time. Either use `ArrayList` with O(1) lookup time, or avoid indexed lookups altogether by using an iterator:

```
for (String word : words) {
    if (!tempList.contains(word)) {
        tempList.add(word);
    } else {
        int firstIndex = tempList.indexOf(word);
        //do some calculations
    }
}
```

---

**Disclaimer:** The above was written under the questionable assumption that `words` is a `LinkedList`. I would still recommend the enhanced-for loop, since it's more conventional and its time complexity is not implementation-dependent. Either way, the suggestion below still stands.

---

You can further improve by replacing `tempList` with a `HashMap`. This will avoid the O(N) cost of `contains()` and `indexOf()`:

```
Map<String, Integer> indexes = new HashMap<>();
int index = 0;
for (String word : words) {
    Integer firstIndex = indexes.putIfAbsent(word, index++);
    if (firstIndex != null) {
        //do some calculations
    }
}
```

---

Based on your latest update, it looks like you're trying to group "keys" by their corresponding "word". If so, you might give streams a spin:

```
List<String> words = getWordsFromDB();
String[] keys = getKeysFromDB();
Collection<String> groupedKeys = IntStream.range(0, words.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                words::get,
                LinkedHashMap::new,   // if word order is significant
                Collectors.mapping(
                        i -> keys[i],
                        Collectors.joining(", "))))
        .values();
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, it would probably be best to move this logic into your database query.

Comment: I'd like to know where you got `O(1)` for `contains` from.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Did I mention `contains`?

Comment: the what else should `lookup` mean, since there was no where mentioned about getting by index.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Really? What does `List.get()` do?

Comment: how did you decide `words` is of type `LinkedList`?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Perhaps I imagined it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino After all that, turns out he is calling `get()` on a `LinkedList`...

Answer (score 2):

You are searching the list twice per word: once for `contains()` and once for `indexOf()`. You could replace `contains()` by `indexOf()`, test the result for -1, otherwise reuse the result instead of calling `indexOf()` again. But you are certainly using the wrong data structure. What exactly do you need `a` for? *Do* you need `a`? I would use a `HashSet`, or a `HashMap` if you need to associate other data with each word.

Comment: I would index the appropriate column in the database and write a query instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So would I, but when I posted this answer no database was in evidence, and there is still no evidence about what is in the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
//1)  if you can avoid using linked list use below solution

List<String> words= getWordsFromDB();  //words list has nearly 120k elements
    //if you can avoid using linked list, use set instead
    Set<String> set=new HashSet<>();
    for (String s:words) {
        if (!set.add(s)) {
          //do some calculations
        }
    }


   //2)  if you can't avoid using linked list use below code
    List<String> words= getWordsFromDB();  //words list has nearly 120k elements
    List<String> tempList = new LinkedList<String>();  //empty list
    //if you can't avoid LinkedListv (tempList) you need to use a set 
    Set<String> set=new HashSet<>();
    for (String s:words) {

        if (set.add(s)) {
          tempList.add(s);
        } else {
          int a = tempList.indexOf(s);
          //do some calculations
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acutally, `tempList` use linear complexity time methods :

```
if (!tempList.contains(words.get(x))) {
```

and

```
int a = tempList.indexOf(words.get(x));
```

It means that  at each invocation of them, the list is in average iterate at half.
Besides, these are redundant. 
`indexOf()` only could be invoked :

```
for (int x = 0; x < words.size(); x++) {

    int indexWord = tempList.indexOf(words.get(x));

    if (indexWord != -1) {
      tempList.add(words.get(x));
    } else {        
      //do some calculations by using indexWord
    }
}
```

But to improve all accesses, you should change your structure : wrapping or replacing `LinkedList` by `LinkedHashSet`.
`LinkedHashSet` would keep the actual behavior because as `List`, it defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set but it also uses hashing feature to improve time access to its elements.